# Error in addon: "wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call"

Tags: python, scripting

In this simple addon example, a button is added to the Render tab of the Properties window

[image]

but when I click on it, I get the error message:

> wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call 'OBJECT_OT_my_operator'

What am I doing wrong?  Here's my code:

```
import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_my_operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname='object.my_operator'
    bl_label="My Operator"

    def exec(self, context):
        print("hello")        
        return {'FINISHED'}

def draw(self, context):      
    self.layout.operator('object.my_operator', text="Operator 1")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.append(draw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: `exec` should be `execute`

Comment: Just mark CoDemans answer since he already gave an extended explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pink vertex pointed out, the method needs to called `execute`.

What happens here?

An operator added to a panel shows as button, and if you click it, Blender will try to invoke it by default (which means it looks for an `invoke()` method in the operator).

Since your operator has no `invoke()`, it will try to execute it instead (thus try to call `execute()`). Your operator doesn't have it, and Blender gives up with the error mesasge:

> wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call 'OBJECT_OT_my_operator'

So it means it couldn't find a method for the operator context (`invoke` for a button in a panel by default), nor an alternative (`execute`).

You can override the operator context in layouts if you need to. If your operator defines `invoke()` and `execute()` alongside, you might want a button in a panel that executes the operator, and not invoke it. Create a layout sub-element (column, row, ...) and set its `operator_context` attribute to the context you want to run it in (see [API docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator_context)):

```
import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_my_operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.my_operator"
    bl_label = "My Operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("hello invoke")
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def execute(self, context):
        print("hello execute")        
        return {'FINISHED'}

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator(OBJECT_OT_my_operator.bl_idname, text="Operator 1 - invoke (default)")

    col = layout.column()
    col.operator_context = 'EXEC_DEFAULT'
    col.operator(OBJECT_OT_my_operator.bl_idname, text="Operator 1 - execute")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_my_operator)
    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.append(draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_my_operator)
    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.remove(draw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```